# jQuery multiple clocks in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I (a javascript newbie) want to have mutiple clocks with different time values in one page.
I managed to get the clock running, but if i add a second clock only one clock is getting displayed. In the console both ids with the correct (different) time are printed.

```
(function($, undefined) {
$.fn.clock = function(currentTime) {

    return this.each(function() {
        var localTime = +Date.now();
        var timeDiff = currentTime - localTime;

        updateClock = function (self, diff) {

            var realtime = +Date.now() + diff;
            var date = new Date(realtime);

            var hours = date.getHours();
            if(hours < 10) hours = "0"+hours;

            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            if(minutes < 10) minutes = "0"+minutes;

            var seconds = date.getSeconds();
            if(seconds < 10) seconds = "0"+seconds;

            var day = date.getDate();

            var month = date.getMonth()+1;

            var year = 1900 + date.getYear();

            if(day < 10) day = "0"+day;

            if(month < 10) month = "0"+month;

            var formattedTime = day + '.' + month + '.' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

            self.text(formattedTime);
            console.log(self.attr("id")+":"+formattedTime);
            setTimeout(function() {updateClock(self, diff)}, 1000);
        };

        updateClock($(this), timeDiff);

    });

};

return this;

})(jQuery);
```

Call (takes time in ms as parameter):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clock").clock(123456789);
        $("#clock2").clock(1234567899);
    });
</script>
```

clock and clock2 are empty divs.
Problem: Only clock2 (the last initialized clock) is displaying the time.

EDIT:

DIVs:

```
<div id="clock"/>
<div id="clock2"/>
```

EDIT2:
It's working now. The divs need an end-tag.

Comment: `updateClock` is a global variable. Add `var`

Comment: your code on jsfiddle works http://jsfiddle.net/7UVBF/7/

Comment: Write your DIV html code please

Comment: Close div tag. Look out my jsfiddle, your code its working fine. Some times we focus the problem on jquery and a correct html is so important!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div's must have end tag

```
Tag omission None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

```
<div id="clock"></div>
<div id="clock2"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`updateClock` is a [implicitly global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) variable. Add a `var`, or make it

```
function updateClock(self, diff) {
```

to scope the function correctly.

Comment: i tried both (var and function), the problem is still there.

Comment: Hm, you're right, since `updateClock` is not a closure but gets passed `self` and `diff` every time explicitly it would work even without that (you should fix this nevertheless). I cannot spot other mistakes in this code, as @Phx demonstrated it does work. The error must be somewhere else.